# An object that works with the += operator for both strings and ints

Tags: python

Is there a way in Python to initialise a variable so that it will work with `+= "a string"` or with `+= 100`?
For example:

```py
a = <what to put here>
a += 100  # a = 100
b = <same what to put here from above>  
b += "a string"  # b = "a string"
```

If I use:

```py
a = ""
a += "a string"  # this will work fine
b = ""
b += 0  # -> TypeError
```

Once the type of the variable has been defined, it is okay to get a `TypeError` afterwards if I try to `+=` a different type. For example:

```py
a = <what to put here>
a += "a string"  # a = "a string"
a += 200  # -> okay to get a TypeError here
```

I’m only interested in making this work for ints and strings.

Comment: You can create your own class and use operator overloading so that objects of this class can cope with adding string or number.

Comment: What should happen if we do `a = ...; a+= 100; a+= "foobar"`?

Comment: Right, I forgot to mention that. Once the type is set/cast to string it is okay to get a type error if I do += 20 (and vice-versa)

Comment: What do you want to happen exactly? What's the end goal? I can't think of a situation where you'd want this off the top of my head, but I also wouldn't be surprised. There might be a better way to do whatever you're trying to do. Beware the [XY problem](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/343832).

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [Overriding "+=" in Python?](/q/1047021/4518341)

Comment: @wjandrea One situation where one might want this is as initial value for `sum`. So that `sum(strings, ...)` works as intended instead of lying `sum() can't sum strings`.

Comment: @Kelly `sum()` doesn't use `+=`

Comment: @wjandrea Right, it rather uses `+`. Related, though, and like you said in the same comment, we might have the XY problem here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
a = type('', (), {'__add__': lambda _, x: x})()
a += 100

b = type('', (), {'__add__': lambda _, x: x})()  
b += "a string"

print([a, b])
```

Output ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3uxIVbBVKKgtSNdTVdRQ0NHUUqtXj4xNTUuLj1a0UchJzk1ISFeJ1FCqsFCpqNTU0uRIVtG0VDA0MuLiSSNOpoADUAdSrlKhQXFKUmZeuxMVVAKRLNKITdRSSYjUhLoI6DOZAAA)):

```
[100, 'a string']
```

Comment: Why on Earth would you create a class with a null name, and why use `type()` instead of just using the `class` syntax? OP never said the code has to be as small as possible, if that's why.

Comment: It's so much more readable as something like this: `class IdentityAdder: def __add__(self, other): return other` then `a = IdentityAdder()` and `b = IdentityAdder()`

Comment: @wjandrea Because that's what the question's code looks like. Starts with `a = <what to put here>`. So I gave them something to put there.

Comment: They didn't say you can't put anything before it though. Even in that case, I don't see why you wouldn't give the class a name.

Comment: @wjandrea Yeah but I don't need to put anything before it, so I didn't. I did give the class a name, it's just empty. No need to think of something more, so I didn't.

Comment: I mean it's effectively nameless since it doesn't show in tracebacks and such. Cf. `print(type('', (), {}))` -> `<class '__main__.'>`

Comment: @wjandrea Meh. In any case, that's irrelevant for the question.

Answer (score 7):

It depends on what you want the result to look like, but one common use of this is the *string-builder* pattern seen in the Java `StringBuilder` class. This is a class which can accept any object in the language and concatenates a string together using the string representations of the constituents. We could write that like so.

```
class StringBuilder:

    def __init__(self):
        self.body = ""

    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.body += str(other)
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body

# Example use
a = StringBuilder()
a += "Hello, "
a += 100
print(a)  # Prints "Hello, 100"
```

If your eventual goal is to build a string, this is what you want. But you can adapt the pattern to other use cases as well. If you want to just delegate to `+` on the underlying type and use this made-up class we're writing as a sort of universal identity, you can do that as well.

```
class UniversalIdentity:

    def __add__(self, other):
        return other

    def __radd__(self, other):
        return other

# Example use

# This uses integer addition
a = UniversalIdentity()
a += 100
a += 200
print(a)  # Prints 300

# This uses string concatenation
a = UniversalIdentity()
a += "Hello, "
a += "world!"
print(a)  # Prints "Hello, world!"
```

Answer (score 3):

Create a class with the `__add__` dunder overloaded:

```py
class DynamicAdder:
    def __init__(self):
        self.arg = None
    
    def __add__(self, other):
        if self.arg is None:
            self.arg = other
        else:
            self.arg += other
        
        return self

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.arg)
        

a = DynamicAdder()
a += 100
b = DynamicAdder() 
b += "a string" 

print(a)
print(b)
```

This outputs:

```
100
a string
```